# BSOD 0xA0 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Had a BSOD that I'm hoping to diagnose. The entry in `Event Viewer` corresponding to the BSOD event reads:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. 
The bugcheck was: 0x000000a0 (0x0000000000000614, 0xffff9c8d183de510, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000).
A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP.
```

A quick look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xa0--internal-power-error shows that since parameter 1 is `0x614` then parameter 2 which corresponds to the `POP_FX_DEVICE` looks to be `0xffff9c8d183de510`.

How do I figure out the "human" name for the device given the information above? Or am I missing information and need to dig through `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`?

Comment: The machine is having issues recovering from Hibernation. Disable Hibernation (Power Management Settings), restart and test.

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a try. Because I was hoping for a more "teach a person to fish" type answer can you maybe describe how you were able to infer that this is a Hibernation problem?

Comment: The Microsoft article you posted and another Microsoft search implicated Hibernation farther down the article.

Comment: Please post the file `MEMORY.DMP` if you wish us to analyze it.

Comment: @harrymc It's a 1.7 GB file. Thanks for the suggestion of looking more closely at the `MEMORY.DMP` file. Had to do a bit more googling on how to debug that file but I think I was able to get to the bottom of what was causing my BSOD.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research into how to debug a `MEMORY.DMP` file I was able to follow the steps in: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/view-contents-dump-file

This process ended up pointing to `\SystemRoot\System32\drivers\sshid.sys`.

Doing a lookup of this with Google yielded: https://www.sysnative.com/drivers/driver.php?id=sshid.sys

This makes sense as I had literally installed the SteelSeries Engine HID Driver yesterday. Looks like the solution is to either update or uninstall.

Comment: You may have found a bug in the driver. Have you considered contacting the driver developer and offering to send them your MEMORY.DMP file? Also, is the BSOD reproducible? If so, how can you trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

The article (and another article) implicated hibernation.

That is, the machine is having issues recovering from Hibernation. Disable Hibernation (Power Management Settings), restart and test.

This should help you.